# Integrating inverse trigonometric functions

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I want to find the integral of $$\frac {\sin^{-1}(\ln x)}{x}$$
I know the best way to find th  integration of trigonometric shirt substitutions is to substitute to eliminate the inverse trigonometric function. However, I tried substitution $\ln x = \arcsin x$ but was unable to proceed to solve the equation.

Comment: Keep in mind that the domain of $x$ is restricted to ($1/e$, $e$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do: $$\int \frac{\arcsin(\ln x)}{x}\,{\rm d}x = \int \arcsin y\,{\rm d}y = y\arcsin y -\int\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\,{\rm d}y,$$ with $y = \ln x$. And that last integral is easy (a direct $z = \sqrt{1-y^2} $ change of variables will kill it). Don't forget to go back to the $x$ variable when you're done.

Comment: What is y substituted for?

Comment: $x=e^y$, $dx=e^y dy$ make you arriving to the second integral in Ivo Terek's answer.

Comment: @Gummy I said right after the integrals,  $y = \ln x $, please read more carefully.. This substituition gives ${\rm d}y = {\rm d}x/x,$ which is already present in the integrand. That's why this change of variables is efficient.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to eliminate the inverse trig function in the way you indicate try $e^{\sin y} = x$ (which comes from $\sin y = \ln x$) so $dx = e^{\sin y}\cos y\ dy$ gives you
$$
\int \frac{\sin^{-1}(\ln x)}{x}dx = \int \frac{\sin^{-1}(\ln(e^{\sin y}))}{e^{\sin y}}e^{\sin y}\cos y\ dy = \int y \cos y\ dy
$$

You can evaluate this integrating by parts where $u=y$ and $dv = \cos y \ dy$.

Comment: Why can't we simply use $sin y = lnx$?

Comment: You can, it just makes the finding of the differentials a little more painful for those not comfortable with implicit differentiation.

Comment: Okay. So the basic technique is always to eliminate the inverse trigonometric functions?

Comment: Also, if you want to improve your typesetting you can render $\sin x$ instead of $sin x$ by putting a \ in front of sin (or cos, ln, arcsin etc)

Comment: I didn't say that, in fact, I said "if you want to ... in the way you indicate". It's a fair heuristic to try to get rid of it, but, it probably won't work in all cases.

Comment: For example how about the integration of $(\arcsin x)(lnx)$ putting $x=\sin t$ doesn't seem to work.